# Python list of booleans comparison gives strange results

Tags: python, list, comparison, boolean

I try:

```
[True,True,False] and [True,True,True]
```

and get
    [True, True True]

but

```
[True,True,True] and [True,True,False]
```

gives

```
[True,True,False]
```

Not too sure why it's giving those strange results, even after taking a look at some other python boolean comparison questions. Integer does the same (replace True -> 1 and False ->0 above and the results are the same). What am I missing? I obviously want

```
[True,True,False] and [True,True,True]
```

to evaluate to

```
[True,True,False]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Others have explained what's going on.  Here are some ways to get what you want:

```
>>> a = [True, True, True]
>>> b = [True, True, False]
```

Use a listcomp:

```
>>> [ai and bi for ai,bi in zip(a,b)]
[True, True, False]
```

Use the `and_` function with a `map`:

```
>>> from operator import and_
>>> map(and_, a, b)
[True, True, False]
```

Or my preferred way (although this does require `numpy`):

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> a = array([True, True, True])
>>> b = array([True, True, False])
>>> a & b
array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> a | b
array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> a ^ b
array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 5):

Any populated list evaluates to `True`. `True and x` produces `x`, the second list.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

You're getting the second value returned.

P.S. I had never seen this behavior before either, I had to look it up myself. My naive expectation was that a boolean expression would yield a boolean result.

Answer (score 1):

`[True, True, False]` is being evaluated as a boolean (because of the `and` operator), and evaluates to `True` since it is non-empty. Same with `[True, True, True]`. The result of either statement is then just whatever is after the `and` operator.

You could do something like `[ai and bi for ai, bi in zip(a, b)]` for lists `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

[`and`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short%20circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not) returns the last element if they all are evaluated to `True`.

```
>>> 1 and 2 and 3
3
```

The same is valid for lists, which are evalueted to `True` if they are not empty (as in your case).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you need to zip through the list. Try a list comprehension of this sort:

```
l1 = [True,True,False]
l2 = [True,True,True]
res = [ x and y for (x,y) in zip(l1, l2)]
print res
```

Answer (score 0):

Python works by short-circuiting its boolean and gives the result expression as the result.
A populated list evaluates to true and gives the result as the value of the second list. Look at this, when I just interchanged the position of your first and second list.

```
In [3]: [True,True,True] and [True, True, False]
Out[3]: [True, True, False]
```