# Compare two lists elementwise with OR

Tags: python, comparison

I want to compare two lists of the same length by their elements with an OR.

```py
>>> [0,0,1,1,0] or [1,1,0,1,0]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

I want the outcome to be

```
[1,1,1,1,0]
```

How can I achieve the desired comparison?

Comment: if there is an error in your code, always put that code in your question.

Comment: are you questioning for bitwise or of for the pythonic thruth or?

Comment: @JasperBart I entered this in the prompt. And bitwise OR

Comment: `[a|b for a,b in zip(list1, list2)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element-wise addition of 2 lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713321/element-wise-addition-of-2-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip()` function is used to iterate over corresponding elements of both lists simultaneously, and then a list comprehension is used to perform the `OR` operation on each pair of elements.

```
list1 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
list2 = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]

result = [a or b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

np.logical_or([0,0,1,1,0], [1,1,0,1,0]).astype(int)
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

And check the answers to this question:

[Python list of booleans comparison gives strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898804/python-list-of-booleans-comparison-gives-strange-results)

Comment: You might want to cast those booleans to `int`s to generate what OP wants. Also lookup [`np.bitwise_or`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = [0,0,1,1,0]
l2 = [1,1,0,1,0]

l = [1 if l1[i] == 1 or l2[i] == 1 else 0 for i in range(len(l1))]
print(l) #Output : [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]

# without using one-liner
l = []
for i in range(len(l1)):
    if l1[i] == 1 or l2[i] == 1:
        l.append(1)
    else: l.append(0)
print(l)
```